# Retrieve data from Firebase which is the child of the child of the root node

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I want to match the ID and password on the login screen and the ID is the child of the root node and the password and others as its child. But my code takes the activity to misbehave and not execute the task.[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBkNy.png)
 Code is as follows:

```
    private void login(){
    final String id1 = id.getText().toString().trim();
    final String pwd1 = password.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(id1)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pwd1)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(User_Login.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
    progressDialog.show();

    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
    DatabaseReference databaseReference1=databaseReference.child(id1);
    databaseReference1.child(pwd1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(pwd1.equals(dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString())){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(User_Login.this,Services.class));
            }
            else{
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "Wrong Id/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please provide us the database structure

Comment: @AlexMamo Sure, I added the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(id1);
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(pwd1.equals(dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString())){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(User_Login.this,Services.class));
        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "Wrong Id/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The problem is that you are adding an extra child, `child(pwd1)` that is not necessary.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But my activity is still misbehaving when wrong password id are entered.
What's wrong in the ELSE part?

Comment: What do you mean with `is still misbehaving when wrong password id are entered`? What is happening?

Comment: When I don't enter the correct credentials, the progress dialog running ends up with a slow flash of white screen and the previous activity opens up, and no Toast is displayed.

Comment: Try to remove the `else statement`. Does make any difference? The `white screen` is the activity behind your top activity and that's why is showing up.